# Error of start of hadoop of the program:PriviledgedActionException 

Tags: c++, linux, hadoop, mapreduce, solaris

I wrote following program

```
using namespace std;

#include "hadoop/Pipes.hh"
#include "hadoop/TemplateFactory.hh"
#include "hadoop/StringUtils.hh"
#include "libpq-fe.h"

extern "C" {
    #include "traverser.h"
}

class IndexMap:public HadoopPipes::Mapper {
  public:
    IndexMap(HadoopPipes::TaskContext & context) { }
    void map(HadoopPipes::MapContext & context) {
        std::vector<std::string> paths = HadoopUtils::splitString(context.getInputValue(), "rn");
        unsigned int k = 4;
        unsigned int l = 0;
        string concatpaths[k];
        if (paths.size() % k == 0) {
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                concatpaths[i] = paths[l];
                l = l + paths.size() / k;
            }

            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                for (unsigned int j = 1; j < paths.size() / k; ++j) {
                    concatpaths[i] = +" " + paths[i * paths.size() / k + j];
                }
            }
        } else {
            l = 0;
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                concatpaths[i] = paths[l];
                l = l + paths.size() / (k - 1);
            }
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k - 1; ++i) {
                for (unsigned int j = 1; j < paths.size() / (k - 1); ++j) {
                    concatpaths[i] = +" " + paths[i * paths.size() / (k - 1) + j];
                }
            }
            for (unsigned int j = 1; j < paths.size() - paths.size() / (k - 1) * (k - 1); ++j) {
                concatpaths[k - 1] = +" " + paths[(k - 1) * paths.size() / (k - 1) + j];
            }
            for (unsigned int i = 0; i < k; ++i) {
                context.emit(concatpaths[i], "0");
            }
        }
    }
};

class IndexReduce:public HadoopPipes::Reducer {
  public:
    IndexReduce(HadoopPipes::TaskContext & context) { }
    void reduce(HadoopPipes::ReduceContext & context) {
        long int count = 0;
        long int result = 0;
        std::vector<std::string> processedpaths = HadoopUtils::splitString(context.getInputValue(), " ");
        result = Configure("/export/hadoop-1.0.1/src/c++/hadoopc++/src/nsindexer.conf");
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < processedpaths.size(); ++i) {
            count = Traverser(processedpaths[i].c_str());
        }
        context.emit(processedpaths[processedpaths.size() - 1], HadoopUtils::toString(count));
    }
};

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    return HadoopPipes::runTask(HadoopPipes::TemplateFactory<IndexMap, IndexReduce> ());
}
```

I started it

```
root@one: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin# ./hadoop pipes -D hadoop.pipes.java.recordreader=true -D hadoop.pipes.java.recordwriter=true -input paths.txt -output out.txt -program bin/parindex
```

according to [this document](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.smith.edu%2Fdftwiki%2Findex.php%2FHadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%252B%252B_Programs_on_Hadoop&ei=Swc_UIyfBoPj4QTC-YBg&usg=AFQjCNGIVyzsLACb65APibo_hafV0UnQ-w&sig2=2BxaE1JSiKVWq0TdTaTpHw).

I got the following error

```
12/08/29 08:02:10 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
12/08/29 08:02:10 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
12/08/29 08:02:10 INFO mapred.JobClient: Cleaning up the staging area file:/tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/staging/root-2093574148/.staging/job_local_0001
12/08/29 08:02:10 ERROR security.UserGroupInformation: PriviledgedActionException   as:root cause:org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException: Output directory file:/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/out.txt already exists 
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileAlreadyExistsException:   Output directory file:/export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin/out.txt already exists
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.FileOutputFormat.checkOutputSpecs   (FileOutputFormat.java:121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:891)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient$2.run(JobClient.java:850)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1093)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:850)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJob(JobClient.java:824)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1261)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.runJob(Submitter.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.run(Submitter.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.main(Submitter.java:494)
```

Comment: Possibly a silly question but have you tried deleting the file out.txt before you start the program?

Comment: @john, before start of my program of the file out.txt wasn't, and after performance there was a directory out.txt. The same mistake arose, when after a key - output specified a directory with the name output

Comment: @john before start of my program of the file out.txt wasn't, and after performance there was a directory out.txt. The same mistake arose, when after a key - output specified a directory with the name output