# Error of start of hadoop of the program: java.io.IOException

Tags: java, linux, hadoop, mapreduce

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Error of start of hadoop of the program:PriviledgedActionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191575/error-of-start-of-hadoop-of-the-programpriviledgedactionexception)

I wrote following program (see [Error of start of hadoop of the program:PriviledgedActionException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12191575/error-of-start-of-hadoop-of-the-programpriviledgedactionexception) ).

I started it

```
root@one: /export/hadoop-1.0.1/bin# ./hadoop pipes -D hadoop.pipes.java.recordreader=true -D    hadoop.pipes.java.recordwriter=true -input input/paths.txt -output outnewdir1 -program bin/parindex
```

according to [this document](http://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&frm=1&source=web&cd=2&cad=rja&ved=0CC0QFjAB&url=http%3A%2F%2Fcs.smith.edu%2Fdftwiki%2Findex.php%2FHadoop_Tutorial_2.2_--_Running_C%252B%252B_Programs_on_Hadoop&ei=Swc_UIyfBoPj4QTC-YBg&usg=AFQjCNGIVyzsLACb65APibo_hafV0UnQ-w&sig2=2BxaE1JSiKVWq0TdTaTpHw).

I got the following error

```
12/08/30 03:40:24 WARN util.NativeCodeLoader: Unable to load native-hadoop library for your platform... using builtin-java classes where applicable
12/08/30 03:40:24 WARN mapred.JobClient: No job jar file set.  User classes may not be found. See JobConf(Class) or JobConf#setJar(String).
12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO mapred.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Creating parindex in /tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/local/archive/-7785595679055918834_2050052313_1927350978/filebin-work--3826230438226227897 with rwxr-xr-x
12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Cached bin/parindex as /tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/local/archive/-7785595679055918834_2050052313_1927350978/filebin/parindex
12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO filecache.TrackerDistributedCacheManager: Cached bin/parindex as /tmp/hadoop-root/mapred/local/archive/-7785595679055918834_2050052313_1927350978/filebin/parindex
12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_local_0001
12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO mapred.Task:  Using ResourceCalculatorPlugin : null
12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: numReduceTasks: 1
12/08/30 03:40:24 INFO mapred.MapTask: io.sort.mb = 100
12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.MapTask: data buffer = 79691776/99614720
12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.MapTask: record buffer = 262144/327680
12/08/30 03:40:25 WARN mapred.LocalJobRunner: job_local_0001
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Application.<init>(Application.java:103)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.PipesMapRunner.run(PipesMapRunner.java:68)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runOldMapper(MapTask.java:436)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:372)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.LocalJobRunner$Job.run(LocalJobRunner.java:212)
12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job complete: job_local_0001
12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Counters: 0
12/08/30 03:40:25 INFO mapred.JobClient: Job Failed: NA
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Job failed!
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.runJob(JobClient.java:1265)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.runJob(Submitter.java:248)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.run(Submitter.java:479)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.pipes.Submitter.main(Submitter.java:494)
```

Comment: The NullPointerException is more of a worry.  Unfortunately you will need to read the code to see what value it expects to be set and see if there is some configuration you forgot to give it it is assuming is there.

Comment: Please do not post the same question multiple times.

Comment: @PeterLawrey And it is possible in more detail on an example of my program?

Comment: It is if you read the code of around line 103 of Application. I haven't read the code myself.